# send Email with multiple attachment and html body which may contain image in java

Tags: java, sendmail

I want to send email with multiple attachment to multiple recepients / multiple CC recepients / BCC Recepients with formateed html content boy which may contain image.

How to do same ?

please suggest.

Comment: Is this running on a web server where the SMTP server is localhost? Or are you launching this from your desktop?

Answer (score 5):

This is working example for sending email for yahoo id to any other id from my local machine.

```
package myWorkingFiles;

import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment;
import org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail;
import org.apache.commons.mail.MultiPartEmail;

/**
 *
 * @author xyz
 */
public class YahooEmailWorkingWithAttachment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myEmailId = "zz@yahoo.com";
        String myPassword = "myPass";
        String senderId = "sfdsdf@gmail.com";
        String ccId = "dddd@yahoo.com";
        String bccId = "ffff@yahoo.com";
        try {
            MultiPartEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
            email.setSmtpPort(587);
            email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(myEmailId, myPassword));
            email.setDebug(true);
            email.setHostName("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
            email.addTo(senderId);
            email.addCc(ccId);
            email.addBcc(bccId);
            email.setFrom(myEmailId);
            email.setSubject("Test Email");
            email.setMsg("<font face='verdana' size='3'>Here is the test email in HTML format "
                    + "<table>"
                    + "<tr><th>id</th><th>Name</th></tr>"
                    + "<tr><th>1</th><th>Name 1</th></tr>"
                    + "<tr><th>2</th><th>Name 2</th></tr>"
                    + "<tr><th>3</th><th>Name 3</th></tr>"
                    + "<tr><th>4</th><th>Name 4</th></tr>"
                    + "</table>"
                    + "</font>");

            // add the attachment
            EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
            attachment.setPath("/Users/alkandari/Desktop/SMART/Fahim/test_small.pdf");
            attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
            email.attach(attachment);

            attachment = new EmailAttachment();
            attachment.setPath("/Users/alkandari/Desktop/SMART/Fahim/test.png");
            attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
            email.attach(attachment);
            System.out.println("EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT==" + EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);

            // send the email
            email.send();
            System.out.println("email=====" + email + "==");
            System.out.println("Mail sent!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception :: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to send from any other you will need to do changes at below two place

```
email.setSmtpPort(587);
email.setHostName("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
```

---

### Edit 1

I am not sure, but if you want to set image as background for email, then I believe you will need to take image  live on server and then give the server path for `<img src="server.com/images/myImage.png" />`

---

### Edit 2

To add more cc, you will need to add N number of cc statement as below.

```
email.addCc("id1@test.com");
email.addCc("id2@test.com");
email.addCc("id3@test.com");
email.addCc("id4@test.com");
```

I am not sure about `email.addCc("id1@test.com, id2@test.com, id3@test.com");`. I think it won't work. You can give a try.

Comment: cc and bcc would be comma seprated String right ? like  email.addCc("test@gmail.com,test1@gmail.com");

Answer (score 0):

By using java mail API you can achive this.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Answer (score 0):

Very clear and simple examples are provided [here](http://tutorial4java.blogspot.in/2012/07/java-mail-api-tutorial.html). Max its enough to solve the problem... :)